# Exclude class or method from code coverage in .net-core

Tags: .net-core

I know i was able to use `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` to exclude code coverage in .Net framework 4.

Does anyone know if there's a way i can exclude code coverage from .dotnet core?

Comment: quick search https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ExcludeFromCodeCoverage

Comment: Still there i guess. Found under here :- 

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Diagnostics.Tools/src/System

guess i should be referencing System.Diagnostics.Tools

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Nope, still not able to add System.Diagnostics.Tools nuget package to my asp.net core projects.

Answer (score 8):

Since .NET Core 2.0 you can use `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public class YourClass
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

https://isscroberto.com/2019/07/11/net-core-exclude-from-coverage/

Comment: Unfortunately this, does not work for me for an Asp.net core 2.2 web api project. I wanted to exclude the OnModelCreating() method that was scaffolded from the dbcontext. But it does not work. Running the code metrics, still shows the method with a very low maintainability index. I would like for that method to not show at all, since it is auto-generated.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found solution!

First of all you need to use .runsettings file to configure code coverage:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

BUT the problem is that ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute is sealed so we can't use it

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/93b277c12c129347b5d05de973fe00323ac37fbc/src/System.Diagnostics.Tools/src/System/Diagnostics/CodeAnalysis/ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute.cs

I posted question here and looks like it will be solved in next release

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14488

FOR NOW
I use GeneratedCodeAttribute as mentioned in .runsettings example.
You can also use your custom attribute or any other exclude rule like here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create your own **ExcludeFromCodeCoverage** attribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute(string reason = null)
    {
        Reason = Reason;
    }

    public string Reason { get; set; }
}
```

Then add it to your **.runsettings** file and exclude it.

```
...
   <Configuration>
      <CodeCoverage>
        .
        .
        .
        <Attributes>
          <Exclude>
            <Attribute>^YourCompany\.YourNameSpace\.sExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
          </Exclude>
        </Attributes>
        .
        .
        .
    </Configuration>
...
```

Don't forget to select your run setting file when analyzing the code coverage.

[More on customizing run settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2015)